# How to convert/rename unknown file type in access vba for fixed imports specification

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to import a bunch of files into access using the fixed (.txt) import specification. However, while these files open in notepad nicely, they are not .txt files and hence the import fails.

The original files come zipped. I have already the below code (extracted and incomplete) to unzip them and place them in a folder. After each import, the unzipped file is then deleted to free space.

```
  If LCase(Right(fil.Name, 3)) = "zip" Then
        Status "Unzip file '" & fil.Name & "'..."
        currentISO = Left(fil.Name, 2)
        UnZipFiles iZip, fil.Path
        iTimeEnlapsed = 0
        'Pause until the file is completely extracted
        Do Until fso.GetFolder(iZip).Files.Count > 0
                Call Sleep(Int(fil.Size / (2 * 20)))
            'If unzip failed after 15sec it will be invoked again
            iTimeEnlapsed = iTimeEnlapsed + 1000
            If iTimeEnlapsed > 50000 Then
                If MsgBox("UnZip Error: " & fil.Name & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to SKIP this file and resume IMPORT process?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "UNZIP Errot - Resume ") = vbYes Then
                     Exit Do
                End If

               UnZipFiles iZip, fil.Path
               iTimeEnlapsed = 0
               Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        For Each fil2 In fso.GetFolder(iZip).Files
            'Import the files (after converting them to .txt)

        DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "Daily_Import", "Import_Data_Dump", fil.Path

        Kill fil2   

        Next fil2
        Set fil2 = Nothing
    Else

  End If
```

After the above code (for each fil2), the import is done form the file path (which is easy to change). However, this will not work if my files does not end with .txt. They are all XXXXX instead of XXXXX.txt, where they do not come with a file extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the file:

```
   For Each fil2 In fso.GetFolder(iZip).Files
       fil2.Name = fil2.Name & ".txt"

       ' Import the file.
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "Daily_Import", "Import_Data_Dump", fil2.Path

       fil2.Delete
   Next fil2
```

Comment: damn i never thought this could work. i feel dumb now...thanks@Gustav